# Variable sized type in Chisel

Tags: chisel

I have the following code that compiles:

```
class S extends Bundle { 
  val channels = VecInit.fill(7)(UInt(32.W))
}
class D extends Module {
  val v = IO(Flipped(Decoupled(new S)))
  v.ready := true.B
}
```

But running a simulation gives the error:

> [error] chisel3.package$ExpectedHardwareException: vec element 'UInt<32>' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type. Perhaps you forgot to wrap it in Wire(*) or IO(*)?

Changing the code to

```
 val channels = VecInit.fill(7)(Wire(UInt(32.W)))
```

or

```
 val channels = VecInit.fill(7)(IO(UInt(32.W)))
```

gives the following error:

> [error] chisel3.package$ExpectedChiselTypeException: Bundle: S contains hardware fields: channels: D.v_channels: Wire[UInt<32>[7]]

How can I define a custom type in Chisel with a (compile time) variable number of channels?

I just want a variable size custom type that compiles and runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the error on Scatie [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LB61bF2xQP2GaMoSEw6m2g).

```
  val channels = VecInit.fill(7)(UInt(32.W))
```

It's not the right way to declare `UInt()` vector. You should declare it like describe in [cookbook](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/cookbooks/cookbook.html#how-can-i-tieoff-a-bundlevec-to-0):

```
  val channels = Vec(7, UInt(32.W))
```

It works in [scatie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CFP6R14oShiI08v6Mi9PKg).